# bash, getting the mime type of a file handle

Tags: bash, mime-types, tar

How would i get the mime type of a file-handle without saving it to disk?

What i mean is a file that is not saved to disk, rather: i extracted it from an archive and plan on piping it to another script.

Say i extracted the file like this:

```
tar -xOzf images.tar.gz images/logo.jpg | myscript
```

Now inside myscript I would like to check the mime type of the file before further processing it. How would it go about this?

Comment: Read enough data off of the front of the pipeline input that you can test for it and then feed that data (and the rest of the piped data) into whatever processing step you perform next?

Comment: I don' t know what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps on the fly file/mime type verification? This `file`-command could probably help: `cat my_on_the_fly_file | file -b --mime-type -`. It determines a file smime type "on the fly".

Comment: Marc,  don't be shy. Post this as the answer.        tar -xOzf images.tar.gz images/logo.jpg | file - b - - mime type -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as some people think my comment above is helpful i post it as an answer.
the `file`-command is able to determine a file's mime type on the fly/when being piped. It ist able to read a file from stdin `-` printing the file's `--mime-type` briefly/in a short manner when passing `-b`. Considering your example you probably want to extract a single file from an archive and dertermine its file/mime type.

```
$ tar -xOzf foo.tar.gz file_in_archive.txt | file -b --mime-type -
text/plain
```

so for a simple text file extracted from an archive to stdout it could look like the example above. hope that helped. regards